# Creating new vector in tensorflow from argmax performed on another tensor

Tags: tensorflow, symbolic-math

I have tensor that has shape `(?, 3)`, looks like this `[x, y, z]` and I need to create function that take *argmax* of it, creates new vector and assign values with respect to dimension and *argmax*.

Example:

```
   f(y):
    v = tf.variable(tf.zeros(y.get_shape()))
    index = tf.argmax(y)
    v[index] = 1.0
    return v
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I can't figure out how can one do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you want to create and assign to a `tf.Variable` here? It would probably be simpler to use the [`tf.one_hot()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#one_hot) op (available from version 0.8 onwards) to build the result functionally, as you wouldn't have to worry about initialization, etc. For example, you could do the following:

```
def f(y):
    index = tf.argmax(y, 1)
    return tf.one_hot(index, tf.shape(y)[1], 1.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: hmmm, it results in three times bigger dimension of tensor. I expect dimension [1024, 3] and I got [3072, 3]. am I doing something wrong? 

vector = tf.one_hot(tf.argmax(y_true, dimension = 0), tf.size(y_true), argmax_target_value, 0.0)

Comment: I modified the answer to handle matrix inputs, but it's not clear from the question which dimension you want to reduce across. Can you give it a try?

Comment: @mrry tf.one_hot() is good. Do we have a list of all new APIs added in 0.8?